EJS Realtime Database Watcher using firebase RDB
sorry i want to ask, do anyone ever do a thing on EJS like Watching a data from RealtimeDB? Thanks!
Example code or some of explanations about a watcher inside of EJS,
i have been trying within some interval time, but it wont work any longer as I expected, until i receive the webhook from the payment gateway
